# Recursive Method to Expand Don't Cares into Binary Numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that will convert input like "---" into 000,001,010,011,100,101,110, and 111. Another example is "1--" -> 100,101,110,111. Here is my code so far, but it is only producing some of the solutions:

```
static void expandPLA(char[]plaRow){
        boolean sawDontCare=false;
        for(int x = 0; x< plaRow.length; x++){
            if(plaRow[x]=='-'){
                sawDontCare=true;
                plaRow[x]='0';
                expandPLA(plaRow);
                plaRow[x]='1';
                expandPLA(plaRow);
            }
        }
        if(!sawDontCare)
            arrayList.add(plaRow);    
    }
```

arrayList holds the output values. Anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: Is the input always 3-char? Or you can get something like "1---011--"?

Comment: It can be any length.

Comment: You're modifying original value of `plaRow` and you'd want `x` out of recursion. Your recursion function should look something like `expandPLA(char[] plaRow, char[] value, int x)`

Comment: A good litmus test for a method like this is - there are obviously 2^n possible strings, where n is the number of `-`s. So, if your method is not coded in such a way that it will recurse/iterate/whatever 2^n times, then your algorithm cannot be right right off the bat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an example implementation for you that prints a list of values like you indicated above.  You, of course, can do whatever you'd like in place of printing to console:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {

    public static void expandPLA(char[] pla) {

        // How many don't cares are we handling
        int empties = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pla.length; i++) {
            if (pla[i] == '-') { empties++; }
        }

        // Now we know we're counting from 0 to 2^empties in binary
        for (int j = 0; j < Math.pow(2,empties); j++) {

            // For each value of j we're going to create a new string pattern
            // and fill in each don't care with the correct digit of j
            String pattern = String.copyValueOf(pla);
            String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(j);

            // Pad bin with zeros
            int pad = empties - bin.length();
            for (int z = 0; z < pad; z++) {
                bin = "0" + bin;
            }

            // For each empty spot we're going to replace a single '-' with
            // the next most significant digit
            for (int k = 0; k < empties; k++) {
                char digit = bin.charAt(k);
                pattern = pattern.replaceFirst("-", String.valueOf(digit));
            }

            // We're just going to print this out for now, but you can do
            // whatever it is you want at this point.
            System.out.println(pattern);

        }

    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Main.expandPLA(new char [] { '1', '-', '-', '1', '-', '1', '-', '-' });
    }

}
```

**Note**: My algorithm above could be tightened up a lot.  I'm lazy in how I pad my binary number with 0's and there is likely a better way to get my digits into the don't care spaces than string replace.  Consider this a proof of concept that could be more memory and time efficient, but one that I believe is superior to recursing.

Comment: Just to point out the obvious, I didn't see this as a good fit for recursion.  Not sure if that is a true requirement or just the direction you chose to try first.

Comment: Recursion (in general) has poorer performance than simply iterating (excusing the 'tail recursion' optimization talked about by @GoZoner, not supported in Java)

Comment: In addition, you're iterating over a flat and eminently iterable domain (number from 0 to N), so recursion takes a simple algorithm and makes it much more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work if you really want a recursion:

```
static final char[] digits = new char[]{'0','1'};

private void expandPLA(char[] plaRow, char[] value, int x) {
    if (x == plaRow.length) {
        arrayList.add(value);
        return;
    }
    if (plaRow[x] == '-') {
        for (char digit : digits) {
            value[x] = digit;
            expandPLA(plaRow, value, x + 1);
        }
    } else {
        value[x] = plaRow[x];
        expandPLA(plaRow, value, x + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recursive, but it is not Java.

```
(define (expand-pla code)
  (define (cons-of x) (lambda (l) (cons x l)))
  (define cons-1 (cons-of #\1))
  (define cons-0 (cons-of #\0))

  (map list->string
       (let building ((codes  (string->list code)))
         (if (null? codes)
             (list '())
             (let ((rest (building (cdr codes))))
               (case (car codes)
                 ((#\0) (map cons-0 rest))
                 ((#\1) (map cons-1 rest))
                 ((#\-) (append (map cons-0 rest)
                                (map cons-1 rest)))))))))
```

Perhaps you might find it interesting.  And, it works:

```
> (expand-pla "1--")
("100" "101" "110" "111")
```

Here is a tail-recursive version.

```
(define (expand-pla code)
  (define (cons-of x) (lambda (l) (cons x l)))
  (define cons-1 (cons-of #\1))
  (define cons-0 (cons-of #\0))
  (define (compose f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))

  (let building ((codes (string->list code)) (result (list '())))
    (if (null? codes)
        (map (compose list->string reverse) result)
        (building (cdr codes)
                  (case (car codes)
                    ((#\0) (map cons-0 result))
                    ((#\1) (map cons-1 result))
                    ((#\-) (append (map cons-0 result)
                                   (map cons-1 result))))))))
```